# ActiveRecord chaining where with or relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I am chaining multiple where's in my model and it's look like that - 
`user.watched_posts.commented_posts`

where watched_posts and commented_posts is just method in the User model that calls where.
Currently the results SQL have AND relationship between those where conditions, 

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE (--watched_posts-) AND (--commented_posts--)`

How can I chain the methods but get and OR relationship? 

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE (--watched_posts-) OR(--commented_posts--)`

I don't want to created method like 'watched_or_commented_posts' because it will be strange...
And I have lot of other methods that will get chained and I need an OR relationship.

Your help will be appreciated,
Yosy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveRecord interface does not provide a wrapper for `or`. It is provided by Arel however, which is what ActiveRecord uses. You can access a model's arel table by using the `arel_table` class method.

Take a look at the OR section of the Arel github:

https://github.com/rails/arel

Comment: Your other option is to just provide the SQL for the OR directly.